# SVG changing paths for mobile version

Tags: svg, mobile, responsive, css-transforms

I would like to make an SVG responsive in the sense that I would like to change my paths into a different ones when they reach certain viewports.
A simple example: an horizontal line becoming vertical when I resize my viewport from desktop to, let's say, 768px.
Is that possible? If so, what approach is preferable?
Thank you

Comment: have two paths and change the display property via a media query so only one is visible at a time.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty easy but what I had in mind was a transformation of the intial path, if possible...

Comment: you could set a CSS transform to rotate and translate the path. That seems more difficult to me though.

Comment: Ok, thank you @RobertLongson. I will give it a try to both!